# How can I enable hash in C++ Standard Library?

Tags: c++, stl, hash, hashtable

I have tried using `#include<hash_map>` and `#include <hash_set>` and I still get the same errors.

Here is my code:

```
void HashTable_chaining::remove( const string & x )
{
    int hash_index = hash( x, theLists.size( ) ) ;

    list<string>&  whichList = theLists[ hash_index ];

    // search to make sure element not present
    for(list<string>::iterator itr=whichList.begin();itr!=whichList.end();itr++) {
        if(*itr==x) {
            theLists[hash_index].erase(itr);
            return;
        }
    }
    // element not found - so nothing to remove
}
```

And my errors are:

```
Error   8   error C2872: 'hash' : ambiguous symbol  c:\users\aaron           johnson\desktop\program 5(johnson- noakes)\program 5(johnson- noakes)\chaining.cpp 32  1   Program 5(Johnson- Noakes)
```

And I have 8 of these errors. Any suggestions? How can I find out which headers have to be included to use hash?

Comment: You didn't look through your C++ Standard Library reference, then?

Comment: You probably want `unordered_map` and `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is hash a function of your own?
If so, try putting it in a namespace of your own and then call the function like

```
int hash_index = yournamespace::hash( x, theLists.size() );
```

If you want to use the std::hash: It is defined in

```
#include <functional>
```

Comment: i tried int hash_index = std::hash( x, theLists.size() ); with functional included and i still got the same errors.

Comment: The usual scheme is to do `using std::hash; hash(whatever);`. Then it will use std::hash for types where that is defined, or use the user-defined hash function from the correct namespace for other types via argument-dependent lookup, without the user having to specifically name the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the entire C++ spec here online, including our friend "std::hash":

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: It should be noted that this is a C++11 feature.

Answer (score 0):

hash_set and hash_map is available in the SGI STL. Take a look at the following pages:

- http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html
- http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html

The documentation and source code is available at this link:

1. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html